# Avoid memory leak with angular's $interval used in countdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

I'm doing a controller that handles a countdown, like this:

```
var addzero;

addzero = function(number) {
  if (number < 10) {
    return '0' + number;
  }
  return number;
};

angular.module('theapp').controller('TematicCountdownController', [
  '$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var intervalPromise;
    return intervalPromise = $timeout((function() {

      var days, daysRound, deadline, hours, hoursRound, minutes, minutesRound, now, seconds, secondsRound;

      now = new Date;
      deadline = new Date('oct 5 2015 00:00:00');

      days = (deadline - now) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
      daysRound = Math.floor(days);
      $scope.dd = daysRound;

      hours = (deadline - now) / 1000 / 60 / 60 - (24 * daysRound);
      hoursRound = Math.floor(hours);
      $scope.hh = addzero(hoursRound);

      minutes = (deadline - now) / 1000 / 60 - (24 * 60 * daysRound) - (60 * hoursRound);
      minutesRound = Math.floor(minutes);
      $scope.mm = addzero(minutesRound);

      seconds = (deadline - now) / 1000 - (24 * 60 * 60 * daysRound) - (60 * 60 * hoursRound) - (60 * minutesRound);
      secondsRound = Math.round(seconds);
      $scope.ss = addzero(secondsRound);

    }), 1000);
  }
]);
```

The task manager tells me that the process of my angular app is increasingly consuming more memory and CPU is being constantly used.

Before implementing this countdown, memory usage and CPU was normal.

Hopefully you can help me preventing this behaviour.

Thanks

Comment: really need a seconds counter (or even single minutes)  when deadline is days away?

Comment: @charlietfl that was what client requested :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `cancel` that `$interval` whenever a `$destroy` happens?

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
});
```